# Add and edit Rich Text Files to project/solution within Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering if anyone was aware of an add-in that allows me to add and edit rich text files in my actual solution or project file. Any .rtf file I add comes up and is edited as a text file.

If not, I was wondering what most people do when they need to add specs or documentation to their project?

Thank you

Comment: I think I remember being able to edit Word documents inside the IDE using some kind of OLE integration when Word was installed. Not sure it's still possible

Comment: If your edition of Visual Studio includes the WYSIWYG HTML editor. Using HTML files may be an option.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I gave Word 2007 a try, no go unfortunately. I have tried the HTML editor, I find it awkward and I really miss cutting and pasting images. For now my solution is just setting vs to opening them in word pad externally.

Comment: Why not to use google docs? you can open your documents directly in a browser window, also you can work concurrently with other people :) (from a browser window inside Visual Studio) I can explain you how to do...

Answer (score 0):

This wont be possibl.e with out OLE integration